# Odoo - 500 Internal Server Error on import models

Tags: python, odoo

In my odoo module, I only have two files:

> ____openerp__.py
>
> ____init__.py

the module is installed. Even iff I add only a single import statement to the init file, like:

> import models

it throws an error on upgrade. If i remove the import statement it does upgrade. The error is:

> XmlHttpRequestError INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

---

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

Any clue what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the code of models?

Comment: I was trying to import models from openerp. I corrected my statement and its fixed. Thanks. 
I basically looked the issue up in /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log and now i'm having clues about what I might've done wrong.

Comment: you should always go there. if you are developing you should install odoo in developement mode where you can see the log in the console. in eclipse or pycharm.